# Axios "POST" request acting differently than Postman when receiving validation error from backend

Tags: reactjs, spring, axios, spring-validation

I am experiencing an issue when trying to receive Spring validation from my back end to the front end.

I have the back end validation set up and when testing in postman I receive the correct messages for each field, that I am validating.

Here is an example from Postman:

My URL - http://localhost:8080/login

The body that I am sending -

```
{
    "username": "",
    "password": ""
}
```

And then the answer that I receive -

```
{
    "password": "Password is required",
    "username": "Please type in your username."
}
```

However when I try to login my web app, I receive error 400 - bad request. And that's the only error I receive, here is a picture of the network tab when logging in.
[Network tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq0Ea.png)

I tried using a normal fetch post, without axios, but I got the same outcome, so I reverted back to axios.

I am always being send to the error catching of the try, catch block if I try to submit empty fields and my code cannot reach the error handling. Or at least that's what I am thinking.

Here is my front-end code, I feel like the issue is something very obvious, unfortunately couldn't find anything on the internet.

https://pastebin.com/yywKkMM3